# The program '[6096] lencod.exe' has exited with code 300 (0x12c)

Tags: visual-studio

The program '[6096] lencod.exe' has exited with code 300 (0x12c).
what does this mean? is there an error? i have a variable named mbBits->mb_total. is the arrow a syntax of some sort or is it just part of the variable name. i'm debugging the code which i downloaded but when i put the variables in the watch window it says "undefined variable 'mbBits' or something like that.

I also used this code to generate a text file

```
void next_macroblock(Macroblock *currMB)
{


FILE * pFile;
pFile = fopen ("myfile.txt","a");
fprintf (pFile, " \t %d \t | \n",mbBits->mb_total);
fclose (pFile);



}
```

but it says that FILE is unidentified and it also tells me to save the code in Unicode Format. I already tried doing that but more errors come out. heeeeeelp

Answer (score 0):

You will need to at least include `<stdio.h>` to get the references to FILE to compile.

The `main()` function also probably has a non-void return value. The value returned is what is displayed in your message. Include a `return(0);` in each possible path to ensure that the value is set to `0` (indicating, by convention, no error) in the program.